# VSCode extension: How can I remove the error message automatically after x amount of time?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a VSCode extension and I have an error message which pops up if my condition turns out true. I want the error message to disappear after for example 5 seconds.

I tried the following approach:

```
let count = 0

if (condition) {
    setInterval(() => {
          count++
    }, 1000);
    while (count <= 5) {    
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage(`Error!`);
    }
}
```

But that didn't work..., How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: then user has to be quick to read the message, some of them disappear, maybe only the info messages, an error/warning/info have different purposes and some needs to be read before it disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the argument that users must be quick to read such an auto-hiding message, I still think it's useful for specific cases. A while ago VS Code had message toasts, which were perfect for this kind of message, but they have been removed. That's why I wrote a replacement using the progress API:

```js
/**
 * Shows a message that auto closes after a certain timeout. Since there's no API for this functionality the
 * progress output is used instead, which auto closes at 100%.
 * This means the function cannot (and should not) be used for warnings or errors. These types of message require
 * the user to really take note.
 *
 * @param message The message to show.
 * @param timeout The time in milliseconds after which the message should close (default 3secs).
 */
export const showMessageWithTimeout = (message: string, timeout = 3000): void => {
    void window.withProgress(
        {
            location: ProgressLocation.Notification,
            title: message,
            cancellable: false,
        },

        async (progress): Promise<void> => {
            await waitFor(timeout, () => { return false; });
            progress.report({ increment: 100 });
        },
    );
};
```

(taken from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-shell-plugins/blob/master/gui/extension/src/utilities.ts)

and

```js
/**
 * Waits for a condition to become true.
 *
 * @param timeout The number of milliseconds to wait for the condition.
 * @param condition A function that checks if a condition has become true.
 *
 * @returns A promise that resolves to true, if the condition became true within the timeout range, otherwise false.
 */
export const waitFor = async (timeout: number, condition: () => boolean): Promise<boolean> => {
    while (!condition() && timeout > 0) {
        timeout -= 100;
        await sleep(100);
    }

    return timeout > 0 ? true : false;
};
```

(taken from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-shell-plugins/blob/master/gui/frontend/src/utilities/helpers.ts)